# How to scale point values by colour within a grid - RStudio

Tags: r, colors, grid, scaling

I am trying to find a solution for scaling values by colour within a grid. These (Z) values also have an X and Y reference. The attached .png file shows that there is not a Z value for each X/Y reference. However, the existing values should appear as points.

Unfortunately, my experience with RStudio is very limited and my knowledge of packages e.g., ggplot2 is not sufficient to solve this problem. I would appreciate your feedback and suggestions.

> > dput(Werte[67230:67250,]) structure(list(X = c("7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04",  "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04",
> > "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04",  "7,24E+04",
> > "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04",
> > "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04", "7,24E+04"),
> > Y = c("-3,25E+04", "-3,24E+03", "-3,24E+04", "-3,24E+04",
> > "-3,23E+04", "-3,23E+04", "-3,23E+04", "-3,23E+04", "-3,22E+04",
> > "-3,22E+04", "-3,22E+04", "-3,21E+04", "-3,21E+04", "-3,21E+04",
> > "-3,21E+04", "-3,20E+04", "-3,20E+04", "-3,20E+04", "-3,19E+03",
> > "-3,19E+04", "-3,19E+04"), Z = c("", "", "", "", "", "",
> > "", "", "", "6,75E+00", "8,25E+00", "8,25E+00", "7,33E+04",
> > "6,50E+00", "6,17E+04", "5,67E+04", "7,17E+04", "5,33E+04",
> > "5,50E+00", "5,50E+00", "6,17E+04")), row.names = 67230:67250, class = "data.frame")

Best regards
NJT

[image]
A small part of the data set. You can see that there is not a Z-value for all X-Y references

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apply ggplot color scale gradient to portion of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398391/apply-ggplot-color-scale-gradient-to-portion-of-data)

Comment: If you need more help than Dylan's link, please post your data as copy/pasteable text, not a picture. If your data is in R and called `my_data`, `dput(my_data[1:20, ])` will give us the first 20 rows, including all class and structure information.

Comment: If you just want a scatterplot with colored points, `ggplot(my_data, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = Z)) + geom_point()` should do it. Though if you have 60,000+ points, a scatterplot may not be the best choice...